# Как сверстать элемент с закругленным углом?

Tags: html, css, svg

Может кто нибудь подсказать, как можно сверстать элемент с вот таким закругленным углом?

[image: часть элемента которая вызывает у меня сложность]

Я пробовал использовать css свойство border-radius, пытаясь сверстать вот такой элемент:

[image: сначала я пытался сделать вот так]

но тогда угол элемента получался "слишком круглым". Возможно я не правильно подобрал проценты, если кто то может подсказать как сделать это с помощью данного свойства или другого css свойства, буду очень благодарен.

После того, как у меня не получилось сверстать такой элемент, я попытался сделать "треугольник" с помощью SVG:

[image: затем попробовал так]

У меня получилось сделать такой треугольник, с помощью двух прямых линий и одной кривой безье, но к сожалению залить его цветом не получается, так как свойство fill закрашивает не тело моего "треугольника", а область слева от кривой безье. У меня мало опыта в создании фигур с помощью SVG, возможно я что то делаю не так. Если кто нибудь подскажет как можно сделать это, без помощи растрового редактора, буду благодарен.

Comment: border-radius: 50px/30px;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Не оно?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.background {
  z-index: -2;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('https://oboi.ws/filters/kelvin_25_8592_oboi_chernyj_fon_s_uzorami_i_zavitkami_1920x1200.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.black {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.white {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0 250px 0 0 / 0 200px 0 0;
}

.white:before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.wrp:before {
  content: "Уголок";
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  transform: rotate(38deg);
  padding: 0 0 50px 20px;
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

h1 {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="black">
    <h1>Александр Сергеевич Пушкин</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="white">
    <div class="wrp">
      <p>Александр Пушкин родился 26 мая (6 июня) 1799 года в небогатой дворянской семье. Начальное образование, как это было принято у дворян, маленький Пушкин получил дома, его обучением занимались учителя и гувернеры, приглашаемые родителями из разных
        стран Европы. При этом, несмотря на яркий ум, будущее светило русской поэзии никак нельзя было назвать прилежным учеником, преподаватели и родные отмечали в нем отсутствие усердия, но со временем мальчик увлекся чтением.</p>
      <p>Уже в возрасте семи лет в Пушкине начал развиваться его творческий талант. Начитавшись Мольера, Лафонтена и Вольтера, он сочинял на французском языке маленькие комедии, басни и даже пытался написать поэму.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я думал ему только треугольник надо ...а оказывается полностью всё :))

Comment: да хоть css хоть svg учить всё равно надо

Answer (score 4):

Собственно наука не сложная

Вы видите перед собой пять точек

Та точка которая регулирует закругление это: `Q300,40` и меняя в большую или меньшую сторону увидите разницу

Остальные точки это координаты:

0,0 - левый верхний угол

300,0 - правый верхний

300,300 - нижний правый

0,0 - опять вернулись в лево вверх

и Q я подобрал опытным путём

```html
<div style="width: 300px;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
   <path d="M0,0 300,0 300,300 Q300,40 0,0"></path>
</svg>
</div>
```